# Need to make a constructor crash when a variable is initiated to null

Tags: java

For example I have the following constructor, one of my requirements is the make the constructor crash when its null.

```
public Test(String test){
    if(test != null){
        anyVariable = null;
    }
}
```

The test case uses the following:
catch(java.lang.Exception e)

Comment: I am getting a java.lang.NullPointer error though.

Comment: Well then why don't you throw an exception???

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html

Comment: This code couldn't possibly give you a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: `NullPointerException` is a subclass of `Exception`.

Comment: [`Objects.requireNonNull(test, "test cannot be null");`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw exception when it is null:

```
if (test == null) {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

If you need a message, do this:

```
if (test == null) {
    throw new Exception("test cannot be null");
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting a compile error: *Unhandled exception type Exception*.

Comment: Well, yes you would because that is what you asked for in your question. You asked that it should throw exception and crash: and that is what you are getting now.

Comment: @CodingYoshi shmosel is not the OP, I think he is joking or alluding to the fact the the constructor does not throw an Exception

Comment: @shmosel nice one. totally got me

Comment: Thanks. Sorry but I haven't learned throw new Exception(); is there any other alternative? I just started learning the basics of java

Comment: @XianChen Sure, just call `test.toString()`. If it's null it'll throw an exception.

Comment: @XianChen if you are learning and that is your requirement, then that should do it. But you should look into exceptions and understand what they are for, and what they do. But again, if you are learning, then that is how you throw an exception.

Comment: @XianChen if you use `test.toString()`, it will throw an exception if `test` is null but you cannot add your own message. Plus when other developers look at your code, it will not be clear that you wanted to throw an exception if `test` is null.

Comment: @codingYoshi Yes I will look into exceptions. It was just a requirement for an assignment. I appreciate your help! Thanks.

Comment: Don't throw Exception (the parent class for Exceptions) - be specific.  In this case, IllegalArgumentException sounds like it clearly expresses what went wrong.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html